# If checkbox group isn't ticked error is returned

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I have a checkbox group which works fine when you tick one but it returns an error if all are left unticked.

Here's the code:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'] as $val) {
$checkbox1results .= $val.",\n";
}
```

This is the error I'm getting back:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
/home/medicom/public_html/memberappform1.php on line 492
```

I'm not great with php so need a way to return nothing in the loop if nothing is ticked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( is_array($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1']) ){
    foreach ($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'] as $val) {
        $checkbox1results .= $val.",\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'])){     // add && is_array($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1']) to check its an array or not
   foreach ($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'] as $val) {
     $checkbox1results .= $val.",\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to var_dump() your session to see what's inside :) Most likely the value is set but not an array, so you could use the is_array() function to check your value

Answer (score 0):

just use...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'])){
   foreach ($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'] as $val) {
   $checkbox1results .= $val.",\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the checkbox isset because empty checkboxes dont post values

```
if(isset($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1']) {
    foreach($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'] as $val) {
      $checkbox1result .= $val.", \n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just validate with an if statement?

```
foreach ($_SESSION['CheckboxGroup1'] as $val) {
if ($val !==""){
$checkbox1results .= $val.",\n";
} else {
echo "Please tick an option";
}
```

Comment: -1, given the fact that it will still throw an error and the `CheckboxGroup1` has not been set / is not an array to be looped through. So the error he is trying to avoid will still show up.